# How to change the title in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, open-source, erp, odoo-10

I have changed the Odoo 10 login page title by using website builder app  but it does not work on the other pages after login. After login when I access different installed apps then the page title shows Odoo with apps name like "Products - Odoo" or "Customers - Odoo".

Answer (score 6):

In `Odoo 10`, we need to edit below `JS` file

`addons/web/static/src/js/abstract_web_client.js`

Change this code:

```
this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Odoo"});
```

With this one:

```
this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "YourPageTitle"});
```

After this, you restart your `Odoo` server to see the changes.

Comment: This does change the title on all pages when you are logged in but not on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

the funciton that change the tilte_part is :

`_title_changed` in the js file : `addons/web/static/src/js/abstract_web_client.js`

it uses `this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Odoo"});`

so you can change the word odoo by something that you need. and costumize the order of the title in `_title_changed` to display it like what ever you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed openeducat packages then it's very simple. Activate the developer options and from there Just go to

`Website` -> `Promote` -> `Optimize SEO`.

In that wizard will get open from there change the title.

[image: Change Title]