# How to change the title of login page and point of sale page in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, erp, odoo-10

I'm trying from a week to change the "odoo 10" pages title, I found a solution in this request:

[How to change the title in Odoo 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526695/how-to-change-the-title-in-odoo-10/44137639#44137639)

It suggests to edit the `addons/web/static/src/js/abstract_web_client.js` file  and to Change this code:

```
this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "Odoo"});
```

With this one:

```
this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "YourPageTitle"});
```

It worked fine with me but the problem that the "login" page title and "odoo pos" page title haven't changed.

Can any one help me please ?.

Answer (score 4):

You can change title on login page follow these setps

- Activate developer mode
- Go to User Interface and click views
- Search layout and select web.layout template
- Change title from here
- Edit title as per you need

Answer (score 0):

You can change title of POS module here: `point_of_sale/views/pos_templates.xml` , find title tag.

for login page change title in `web.layout` template 
  `web/views/webclient_templates.xml`
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Did you get the answer?